# Plot coastline and calculate distances (marmap and ggmap)

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, distance, ggmap

I am working on a research project in marine ecology, using R, and I would like to create a map of a small and precise part of the French Mediterranean coast. From this map I would like to add the different fish collection sites in order to calculate the distances between these sites, taking into account the topology of the coast (the sites being very close to the coast). I have used the marmap package to do this, however due to the size of the map I wish to create, the resolution is very poor and the map is unworkable.

`data <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 =2.97,lon2 =3.53,lat1 =41.9,lat2 =42.3,resolution = 1)`

I would like to know if there is an alternative, such as using the ggmap package to get a map with a good resolution, then import the GPS points of the sites and calculate the distances between them using marmap ? Are the two packages compatible?

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using `leaflet` for mapping and `geosphere` to find the Haversine (as the crow flies`  distance betwen points.

Comment: is it possible to take into account the topology of the coastline with the ```geosphere``` package? because working with the haversine formula would distort my distance calculations, which must correspond to the topographical reality

Comment: No, I don't think you can find "on the ground up and down" distance that way.

Comment: but is it possible to take into account at least the coastline to avoid distances cutting across the land?

Comment: No, you may need to use shapefiles